# Try block won't run all the way through

Tags: java, try-catch, bufferedreader

What I'm trying to do - Create a program that will read a text file, and basically convert it into a 2D array. Each individual character will take up a slot in the 2D array. 
My problem - My code won't run all the way through the try block. It just stops at some point, which I believe to be in the for loop, just after the //System.out.println("2");. I believe this is the issue because, upon running the code, the "System.out.println"'s don't properly match the number of characters in my created text file. Count them for yourself, if you wish. Also, System.out.println("Problem Fixed"); never runs. This makes me think that the try block is exited, and I cant figure out why. No exception seems to be thrown, and no error appears. I tried looking this up, but haven't yielded any useful results. Me printing out the random numbers into the code were used for three reasons... Reference points for your answers, reference points for my description, and for working through the code mentally after it runs.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        int arrRowSize = 0;
        int arrColSize = 0;
        String currChar;

        System.out.println("Enter file name located in C Drive: ");
        String fileNameEntered = new String(input.nextLine());
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\" + fileNameEntered + ".txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage() + "File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Starting to read lines
        try {
            // Getting 2D array dimensions
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.length() > arrColSize) {
                    arrColSize = line.length();
                }
                arrRowSize += 1;
            }
            String[][] arr = new String[arrRowSize][arrColSize];

            // Filling 2D array with text file
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\" + fileNameEntered + ".txt"));
            int rowNum = 0;
            int colNum = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println("1");
                if (line != null) {
                    // System.out.println("2");
                    for (int c = 0; c < line.length(); c++) {
                        // System.out.println("3");
                        if (c + 1 == line.length()) {
                            // System.out.println("4");
                            currChar = line.substring(c, line.length());
                        } else {
                            // System.out.println("5");
                            currChar = line.substring(c, c + 1);
                        }
                        // System.out.println("6");
                        arr[rowNum][colNum] = currChar;
                        colNum += 1;
                    }
                }
                rowNum += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("Problem Fixed");
            // Printing 2D array
            for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
                System.out.println("inLoop");
                for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[row][col]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            System.out.println(ioex.getMessage() + "Error reading file");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Closed");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't close your `BufferedReader`s. Currently this is not a problem, but with a larger program you will run into problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `colNum` keeps incrementing and incrementing...

You should reset the `colNum` to 0 after reading each row / line, otherwise you will get sooner or later an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thank you! It did in fact solve the problem. I hadn't realized that in a try/catch, the exception would go unnoticed. Once I thought about it, it made sense. But I would like to give some credit to @kaws84, also. He told me specifically where to modify it, which saved me a little time, though you solved the issue first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program on linux machine and it didn't have any problem. Modified program is (i just made change file path).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    int arrRowSize = 0;
    int arrColSize = 0;
    String currChar;

    System.out.println("Enter file name located in current Drive: ");
    String fileNameEntered = new String(input.nextLine());
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/torreto/prog/java/" + fileNameEntered + ".txt"));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex){
        System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage() + "File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //Starting to read lines
    try{
        //Getting 2D array dimensions
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.length() > arrColSize){
                arrColSize = line.length();
            }
            arrRowSize += 1;
        }
        String[][] arr = new String[arrRowSize][arrColSize];

        //Filling 2D array with text file
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/torreto/prog/java/" + fileNameEntered + ".txt"));
        int rowNum = 0;
        int colNum = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println("1");
            if(line != null){
                //System.out.println("2");
                for(int c = 0; c < line.length(); c++){
                    //System.out.println("3");
                    if(c+1 == line.length()){
                        //System.out.println("4");
                        currChar = line.substring(c, line.length());
                    } else{
                        //System.out.println("5");
                        currChar = line.substring(c, c+1);
                    }
                    //System.out.println("6");
                    arr[rowNum][colNum] = currChar;
                    colNum += 1;
                }
            }
            rowNum += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Problem Fixed");
        //Printing 2D array
        for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
            System.out.println("inLoop");
            for(int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++){
                System.out.print(arr[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch(IOException ioex){
        System.out.println(ioex.getMessage() + "Error reading file");
    } finally{
        System.out.println("Closed");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
}
```

output is:

```
Enter file name located in current Drive: 
1
Problem Fixed
inLoop
qwerty gg g    gggg
Closed
```

I think this problen is occuring in windows either due to file name extension (.txt is default for text file) or you don't have access to file in c drive.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what Thomas Kläger mentioned and when you have multiple lines in your file.

Try catching Exception and you will see that the error is: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Adding `colNum = 0;`
where `rowNum += 1;` is, should resolve your issue.